# Can we deploy workloads and services on GKE when the cluster is in repair mode?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, cluster-computing, repair

I deployed my GCP GKE cluster as a Stable channel with version 1.24.8-gke.401, it had 2 node-pools with e2-standard-32 and e2-medium sizes.
Today I added a new node-pool with a size e2-standard-32 and after that my cluster has gone in repair mode, it took 35 mins for this repair to get completed.

After that it worked fine, but then one hour later again it went on repair mode. I just want to make sure if I can deploy the deployment YAML's on the cluster when it is in the repair mode?

Can anyone please guide me here as I'm very new to GKE.

I tried checking my node-pools auto-repair and auto-upgrade modes and it was enabled by default due to the stable release channel at cluster level hence I cannot uncheck that option.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, the Kube API server should still be available while repair operations are occurring.  If the operation is repairing the control plane (which might have been what's happening in your case as adding nodes may have triggered a resize of the control plane), then assuming you have created a regional cluster, you'll still be able to deploy on existing nodes.